# INDIRECT function to reference cell ranges of other worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I am struggling to deduce a way to make dynamic INDIRECT references to cell ranges on other worksheets. Would appreciate any suggestions, details are:

The workbook includes 4 worksheets (Product1, Product2, Product3, Warehouses). The Warehouses sheet contains the following formula to populate an inventory list for each warehouse from the three product worksheets (derived from http://exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/). This is the formula in cell B3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B$3:B$400"),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT(B$2&"!$C$3:$C$400")=$B$1,ROW(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B$3:B$400"))-ROW(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B$3"))+1),ROWS(Product1!$B$3:$B3))),"")
```

Where:

Warehouses-->$B$1 = Warehouse1 or Warehouse2

Warehouses-->B2, C2, D2 = Column headers for Product1, Product2, Product3

Product Sheets-->Column B = Serial #

Product Sheets-->Column C = Location (Warehouse1, Warehouse2)

Currently, I have to amend the last part of the formula for each row: `ROWS(Product1!$B$3:$B3)`, `ROWS(Product2!$B$3:$B3)` , `ROWS(Product3!$B$3:$B3)`.I am trying to dynamically link it to the column header like the other parts of the code (e.g. `ROW(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B$3:B$400"))`. I'm stuck though because the range `$B3` has to change with each row, whereas the others are static and are fine enclosed in the quotations.

This effort is important because I want less capable users to be able to copy the formula to new columns without having to amend it. Appreciate any thoughts on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to introduce an incrementing number into the [INDIRECT function's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) string concatenation. I prefer a simple [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/row-function-fde8c59b-a604-4474-90b2-2c69040344f0) like `ROW(1:1)` which returns *1, 2, 3, ...* when filled down. In your case,k yu would start at `ROW(3:3)`.

```
... -ROW(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B"&ROW(3:3)))+1),
..., ROWS(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B3:B"&ROW(3:3))),"")
```

Just a reminder; leaving the absolute $ designations on the cell addresses that are described with text may be useful as a visual reminder as to what may advance to the next (relative) or not (absolute) but the text representing the row or column is *never* going to actually change so they are at least a bit superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeeped. I am in need of a column function rather than row. I have to amend the last part of the formula for each column since `ROWS(Product1!...` is hardcoded into the formula. I am hoping there is a way to tie the sheetname to the values in row 3 of the 'Wares' sheet so as to not need to change the formula from `ROWS(Product1!...` to `ROWS(Product2!...`, etc. I realize it's difficult to explain so I've linked to an example in Google Sheets (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vsCDYIFKe6aTeXK1O_5NNmbWIzhr1qUg4EvPzn2AYnw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Nevermind me Jeeped, I initially misused your suggestion but realized its brilliance after some playing. Thanks so much! This has been on my to-do list for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `INDIRECT()` formula to take into account the row number of current cell, for example:

```
=INDIRECT(B$2&"!B$"&ROW()&":B$"&(ROW()+397))
```

Alternatively, you could use `OFFSET()` function to shift your reference with each row:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(B$2&"!B$3:B$400"),ROW()-3,0)
```

Comment: Sorry for any confusion Taosique. I need to amend the reference to a range in other sheets ROWS(SHEETNAME!$B$3:$B3), not references to ranges in the sheet containing the formula. Doing something like ROWS(INDIRECT(B$2&"!"&$B$3:$B3)) points to range $B$3:$B3 in the current sheet, not the sheet referenced in B2. Does that make sense?